# Convert a pandas Dataframe into a network graph

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

Given a DataFrame with `n` rows and 2 columns. I would like to turn this into a graph by the following simple rule: an edge exists between two (different) nodes (or rows) if their corresponding column values are the same. For example, if row 1 has value A and row 2 has value A then they are connected. Is there an efficient way to convert this Df into one with source and target columns appropriate for the `Networkx from pandas_edgelist` that does not involve looping over the entire Df multiple times ?

Example Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
  
lst = ["A", "B", "C", "A"]
lst2 = ["W1", "W2", "W1", "W3"]

df = pd.Dataframe(list(zip(lst, lst2)), columns=["red", "blue"])
```

In this case, since the "A" and "C" rows share the same "blue" column values of "W1", there would be an edge between "A" and "C" nodes.

Comment: Please provide your code and an example dataset. The is no reason why you would need to loop.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @endeavor please share minimal data with us

Comment: I have added a minimal example Dataframe.

Comment: Do you mean like `G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source="red", target="blue")`? (After `import networkx as nx`.)

Comment: @Timus yes but this would mean that the values in the "blue" column would be nodes but I do not what that.

Comment: Could you extend your example a bit and add the expected output?

Comment: @Timus the expected output would be a networkx graph with nodes: A,B,C and edges: A-C

Comment: By extend I meant to make it a bit larger. I.e., what should happen when there’s another row with `{'red': 'D', 'blue': 'W1'}`? (You probably would get more answers if users wouldn’t have to ask such questions.)